# Summation using several roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, summation, roots, roots-of-unity

Don't these roots sum to $0$? Then how do I evaluate this sum? The question is:
$U$ denotes a set of complex roots to $a^{1020}  = 1$ and $P$ denotes the set of complex roots to $b^4 = 1$. $K = U - P$.

The equation is 
$$
\bigg\lvert \sum_{y \epsilon K}^{} \frac{1+y}{-y^3+y^2-y+1}\bigg\rvert^2
$$

Comment: This is equivalent to $$\bigg|\sum\limits_{y\in K}\dfrac{(1+y)^2}{1-y^4}\bigg|^2$$

Comment: Try dividing the numerator and denominator by $y+1$.

Comment: Have you tried considering roots and their complex conjugates (which also are roots)>

Comment: My train of thought was that the roots of $a^{1020}=1$ were $e^{(k*i*pi)/1010}$. Do these also have complex conjugates?

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a series of simplifications until the problem is trivial:

1. Note that $-1 \not\in K,$ and $$y\neq -1 \implies \frac{1+y}{-y^3+y^2-y+1} = \frac{(1+y)^2}{1-y^4}$$
2. Set $f(y) = \dfrac{(1+y)^2}{1-y^4}.$  Then note that $K$ is symmetric over the point $0,$ so 
   $$\sum_{y\in K} f(y) = \sum_{y\in K} \frac{1}{2}(f(y) + f(-y)) = \sum_{y\in K}\frac{1+y^2}{1-y^4} = \sum_{y\in K}\frac{1}{1-y^2}$$
3. Set $g(y) = \dfrac{1}{1-y^2}.$  Then note that $K$ is symmetric over the real line, so $$\sum_{y\in K} g(y) = \sum_{y\in K} \frac{1}{2}(g(y) + g(\bar{y})) = \sum_{y\in K}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}|K|$$
4. Since $|U| = 1020, |P| = 4,$ and $P \subset U,$ it follows that $$\frac{1}{2}|K| = \frac{1}{2}(1020 - 4) = 508$$
5. We conclude the answer is $508^2 = 258064$

---

**Point(s) of Clarification from the Comments:** (before I delete them to tidy up)

- By "$K$ is symmetric over the point $0$" I mean $y \in K \iff -y\in K.$  Similarly, by "$K$ is symmetric over the real line" I mean $y \in K \iff \bar{y}\in K$ where $\bar{y}$ denotes the conjugate of $y.$  In both cases, the important part is that the symmetry gives a permutation of $K.$  This is because what follows is an instance of the following more general method: $$\rho : K \to K \text{ is a permutation } \\ \implies \sum_{y\in K} F(y) = \sum_{y\in K} F(\rho(y)) \\ \implies \sum_{y\in K} F(y) = \sum_{y\in K} \left(\frac{F(y) + F(\rho(y))}{2}\right)$$ When $\rho$ has order two (i.e. $\rho(\rho(y)) = y$), which is the case in steps 2 and 3 above, this averaging of $F(y)$ and $F(\rho(y))$ tends to simplify sums.  For a more concrete example of this method, note that $\rho(k) = n+1-k$ is a permutation of $\{1,2,3,\ldots, n\},$ so $$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k + (n+1-k)}{2} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n+1}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: Hi again! Are there any resources/explanations you could offer for that symmetry in regard to this problem? Why is that true? I'm trying to grasp the intuition behind it. Additionally, in step 3, is it a property of sums to pull the K into the terms? And why does the sum of g(y) and its conjugate equal 1? Thank you! (sorry that I need so much clarification)

Comment: At the end of step 3, I use $\sum_{y\in K} 1 = |K|,$ which follows since the summands are now constant (they don't depend on $y$) so it just counts the number of elements in $K.$  As for why $g(y) + g(\bar{y}) = 1,$ this isn't something I was expecting, but if you just evaluate the left-hand side (e.g. multiply $g(\bar{y})$ by $y^2$ in the numerator and denominator, and then use $y\bar{y} = |y|^2 = 1$) then you should see it equals $1.$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat more pedestrian answer than the very elegant one [given by Bran Moehring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3422369/summation-using-several-roots/3422425#3422425). Although the underlying ideas are essentially the same, I've used more tedious (and unfortunately, therefore, more error-prone) calculation in place of some of the ingenuity needed to come up with his answer.

Since $\ K=\left\{ e^\frac{(255m+n)2\pi i}{1020}\big\vert\,m,n\in\mathbb{Z},0\le m\le3, 1\le n\le 254\right\}\ $, then if you put $\ r_{m,n}=e^\frac{(255m+n)2\pi i}{1020}\ $, and use [Don Thousand's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/572204/don-thousand) observation you can write your sum as
$$
S=\bigg\lvert\sum_{m=0}^3\sum_{n=1}^{254}\frac{\left(1+r_{m,n}\right)^2}{1-r_{m,n}^4}\bigg\rvert^2\ ,
$$
which can be further simplified by using the facts that $\ r_{m,n}^4=e^\frac{2\pi in}{255}\ $, $\ r_{0,n}^2=r_{2,n}^2=-r_{1,n}^2=-r_{3,n}^2=e^\frac{2\pi in}{510}\ $, $\ r_{0,n}=-r_{2,n}=e^\frac{2\pi in}{1020}\ $, and $\ r_{1,n}=-r_{3,n}=e^\frac{2\pi i(255+n)}{1020}\ $, giving
\begin{align}
S&=\bigg\lvert\,4\sum_{n=1}^{254}\frac{1}{1-\rho_n}\bigg\rvert^2\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ \rho_n=r_{0,n}^4=e^\frac{2\pi in}{255}\ $.  Now observe that $\ \rho_{255-n}=e^{-\frac{2\pi in}{255}}=$$\frac{1}{\rho_n}\ $, so $\ \frac{1}{1-\rho_{255-n}}=\frac{1}{1-\rho_n^{-1}}=-\frac{\rho_n}{1-\rho_n}\ $, $\ \frac{1}{1-\rho_n}+\frac{1}{1-\rho_{255-n}}=1\ $, and the sum becomes
$$
S=\bigg\lvert\,4\sum_{n=1}^{177}1\,\bigg\rvert^2=508^2\ .
$$

Comment: Where did the 254 and 3 come from?

Comment: Every integer $\ y\ $ in the set $\ 0,1,2,\dots, 1019\ $ can be written as $\ y=255m+n\ $, where $\ 0\le m=\left\lfloor\frac{y}{255}\right\rfloor\le3\ $ and $\ 0\le n=y\pmod{255}\le 254\ $. Thus we can enumerate $\ U\ $ as $$\left\{ e^\frac{2\pi i y}{1020}\big\vert\,y\in\mathbb{Z},0\le y\le 1019\right\}\\
=\left\{ e^\frac{2\pi i(255m+n)}{1020}\big\vert\,m,n\in\mathbb{Z},0\le m\le3, 0\le n\le 254\right\}\ .$$
But when $\ n=0\ $, $\ y=255m\ $ and $\ e^\frac{2\pi i y}{1020}=e^\frac{2\pi i m}{4}\in P\ $, and so we have to  remove those elements from $\ U\ $ to get $\ K\ $.